# How to run a script as root and current user at the same time?

Tags: shell-script, sudo

I want to write a shell script that will require `sudo` privilege to do certain task, but also need to change certain configuration as current user. I want to automate the script as much as possible so it does not need any user intervention.

The problem I have is that if I run the whole script as `sudo`, I cannot change current user's configuration. But if I just add `sudo` to the specific command that require root privilege, I will need to keep input the password because the script is long and `sudo` will time out.

Is there a way I can run the script in current user, but keep the `sudo` privilege when I need it?

Comment: For the commands that need root, configure sudoers to allow the current user to perform them without requiring a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two ways to go:

- separate the subtask which needs root access into a different program/script, and run that part as root (either via a setuid root binary, or via `sudo`)
- run the whole thing as root, and do the part which has to be run as a normal user via `su - user`